# Connecting to WMS, but only getting blank pages

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, wms

I have a problem connecting to my WMS service.

In ArcMap I can connect but, what I see is only blank page (cannot see the layers).

<s>In QGIS it also connects with service but when I choose add layers I got this message:</s>
<sub>(picture removed in previous edits, due to non English text).</sub>

[image]

Some of my WMS properties:

```
Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_WGS_1984
Datum: D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian: Greenwich
Angular Unit: Degree
```

And I have additional question: Can I set the version of my WMS when creating in Arcgis Server? Because what I can see is only possibility to set a WMS capability (default version is set up to 1.3.0).

---

I think now I know what is my problem. Look this screen from ArcInfo. Here we got (below) my WMS service and above we have got our governmental geoportal. As I can see that my WMS have no style how it should be display and I think that is why I get white page.

[image]

Do you know how I can set up a styles of display for my layers?

---

I do not know if it is what you expect (response from fiddler), because I never used this software, but this is what I get:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Content-Type: application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml
>   Content-Length: 4807

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE WMT_MS_Capabilities SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd">
<WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1">
  <Service>
    <Name>WMS</Name>
    <Title>karpaty</Title>
    <Abstract>OGC:WMS</Abstract>
    <KeywordList><Keyword></Keyword></KeywordList>
    <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://sasanka/arcgis/services/karpaty/MapServer/WMSServer"/>
    <ContactInformation>
      <ContactPersonPrimary>
        <ContactPerson></ContactPerson>
        <ContactOrganization></ContactOrganization>
      </ContactPersonPrimary>
      <ContactPosition></ContactPosition>
      <ContactAddress>
        <AddressType></AddressType>
        <Address></Address>
        <City></City>
        <StateOrProvince></StateOrProvince>
        <PostCode></PostCode>
    <Country></Country>
      </ContactAddress>
      <ContactVoiceTelephone></ContactVoiceTelephone>
      <ContactFacsimileTelephone></ContactFacsimileTelephone>
      <ContactElectronicMailAddress></ContactElectronicMailAddress>
    </ContactInformation>
    <Fees></Fees>
    <AccessConstraints></AccessConstraints>
  </Service>
  <Capability>
    <Request>
      <GetCapabilities>
        <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://sasanka/arcgis/services/karpaty/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
    </DCPType>
  </GetCapabilities>
  <GetMap>
    <Format>image/bmp</Format>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Format>image/tiff</Format>
    <Format>image/png</Format>
    <Format>image/gif</Format>
    <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
    <DCPType>
      <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://sasanka/arcgis/services/karpaty/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
    </DCPType>
  </GetMap>
  <GetFeatureInfo>
    <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
    <Format>text/xml</Format>
    <Format>text/html</Format>
    <Format>text/plain</Format>
    <DCPType>
      <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://sasanka/arcgis/services/karpaty/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
    </DCPType>
  </GetFeatureInfo>
</Request>
<Exception>
  <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_xml</Format>
  <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage</Format>
  <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_blank</Format>
</Exception>
<Layer>
<Title>Layers</Title>
<SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:32634</SRS>
<LatLonBoundingBox minx="15.369115" miny="42.714826" maxx="28.448058" maxy="50.916128"/>
<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:32634" minx="103146.441764" miny="4749185.807754" maxx="1025945.407535" maxy="5640498.037174"/>
  <Layer queryable="1">
    <Name>0</Name>
    <Title>KEO_boundaries</Title>
    <Abstract>KEO_boundaries</Abstract>
    <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
    <SRS>EPSG:32634</SRS>
    <LatLonBoundingBox minx="16.000407" miny="43.105244" maxx="27.806285" maxy="50.551787"/>
    <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:32634" minx="145091.849299" miny="4789700.000000" maxx="984000.000000" maxy="5599983.844928"/>
    <Style>
      <Name>default</Name>
      <Title>KEO_boundaries</Title>
      <LegendURL width="100" height="11">
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <OnlineResource xlink:href="http://sasanka:8399/arcgis/server/arcgisoutput/karpaty_MapServer/wms/default0.png" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
      </LegendURL>
    </Style>
    <ScaleHint min="0.000000" max="0.000000"></ScaleHint>
  </Layer>
  <Layer queryable="1">
    <Name>1</Name>
    <Title>KEO_cities</Title>
    <Abstract>KEO_cities</Abstract>
    <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
    <SRS>EPSG:32634</SRS>
    <LatLonBoundingBox minx="16.052845" miny="43.138555" maxx="27.772561" maxy="50.532480"/>
    <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:32634" minx="148685.896439" miny="4793261.445014" maxx="981780.187500" maxy="5597836.982627"/>
    <Style>
      <Name>default</Name>
      <Title>KEO_cities</Title>
      <LegendURL width="100" height="15">
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <OnlineResource xlink:href="http://sasanka:8399/arcgis/server/arcgisoutput/karpaty_MapServer/wms/default1.png" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
      </LegendURL>
    </Style>
    <ScaleHint min="0.000000" max="0.000000"></ScaleHint>
  </Layer>
</Layer>
```

Comment: Sorry- messeage is in Polish language. I means that:
I cannot display 1/0 because:
Network connection was closed after 20 seconds.
It can be affected because of problem in local network or WMS.URL server problem: http and so on.

Comment: I assume its not a public WMS that we can test from our ends?
I find Gaia a good WMS client to test in.

Comment: Unfortunately it also does not work with Gaia. Exactly the same situation it connects to WMS service but when i add layers i get blank page.

Comment: You mention your serving it up through ArcGIS Server as 1.3.0
Do you have any security enabled at the ArcGIS Server services end?  What happens if you click on WMS through the REST endpoint?  What happens if you do a getcapabilities request on it - does it return good looking XML?

Comment: I assume that it's just that: The requests timeouts, probably because the server is slow, busy or busy-looping. That would point to a problem in the map service or server configuration.

Comment: Can you download [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and attach a log of you trying to hit the WMS. It may yield some clues onto where the problem lies.
(Comment on this thread with your results)

Comment: Ad. Simon
I have "Enable security for GIS Service" box do not checked.
Yes, if i do a getcapabilities request on it- it returns good looking XML.

Now I am wondering maybe it is a scale problem? I set the scale to hole extend. Anyway i suppose it should be working well...

Comment: Sorry for my post. How can i attach a file here? Because below it is not hole response...

Comment: Are your permissions right to view the data?

Comment: com, can you please add the responses you've posted as 'answers' to the body of the question? Its difficult to follow the order of things you've tried as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help you on Qgis because I never encounter this problem.
In ArcGIS, you need a patch to see WMS 1.3 layers (due to a bug), http://lab.usgin.org/applications/doc/arcmap-extension-adjust-invalid-wms-130-requests for ArcGIS 9.3.1

Comment: Unfortunately this patch did not help to solve my problem. In fact now i can get response from WMS 1.3.0 version (i have check another WMS) but it still did not work with my one...